Writing to FlatGeoBuf using Python OGR results in "ERROR 1: ICreateFeature: Mismatched geometry type"
When I try to create even very basic point geometries using OGR's FlatGeoBuf driver in Python, I keep getting this error: "ERROR 1: ICreateFeature: Mismatched geometry type"
Here is a minimal example:
from osgeo import ogr

output_file = "output.fgb"
driver_name = "FlatGeoBuf"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(driver_name)

data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(output_file)

srs = ogr.osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326) 
layer = data_source.CreateLayer("layer_name_here", srs, ogr.wkbPoint)

feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(10.0, 20.0)  
feature.SetGeometry(point)

# ERROR 1: ICreateFeature: Mismatched geometry type
layer.CreateFeature(feature)

I've tried this on both GDAL 3.7.1 and 3.8.3, MacOS and Windows respectively.
What am I doing wrong here?

AddPoint creates an XYZ geometry (with 0 as the default value for Z) but the FlatGeobuf layer seems to require XY geometry. Use AddPoint_2D instead of AddPoint.
from osgeo import ogr

output_file = "output.fgb"
driver_name = "FlatGeoBuf"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(driver_name)

data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(output_file)

srs = ogr.osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326) 
layer = data_source.CreateLayer("layer_name_here", srs, ogr.wkbPoint)

feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
feature2 = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(10.0, 20.0)  
feature.SetGeometry(point)

point2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point2.AddPoint_2D(10.0, 20.0)  
feature2.SetGeometry(point2)

print(feature)
#  POINT Z (10 20 0)
print(feature2)
#  POINT (10 20)

# ERROR 1: ICreateFeature: Mismatched geometry type
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
# No error
layer.CreateFeature(feature2)

